# How to omit powershell parameter from cmdlet if value not provided?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to execute a below Powershell command to create a new address list on exchange server with parameters like Name, Container, etc.

`Container` is an optional input/parameter, how do I omit it from cmdlet if its value is not provided?

I tried with `IF` conditionals but but does not seems working. Any help here?

```
New-AddressList -Name -Container \test MyAddressList5 -ConditionalStateOrProvince maha -IncludedRecipients MailboxUsers
```

Comment: We can't advise how to not include it if we don't know how are you getting the input? You might want to include a bit more code to show context :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass needed parameters with their corresponding values via **hashtable**. Add `If/Else` conditions to include properties. Like so:

```
$Container  = '\test MyAddressList5'

$Parameters = @{}
$Parameters.Add('ConditionalStateOrProvince','maha')
$Parameters.Add('IncludedRecipients','MailboxUsers')
if($Container){$Parameters.Add('Container',$Container)}

New-AddressList @Parameters
```

Also, when you need to include `Switch` parameter just pass `$True`. Like so:

```
$Parameters.Add('SomeSwitchParameter',$True)
```

Comment: Yes, Hashtable. I have used Hashtable and the purpose is served. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation for the `-Container` parameter in `New-AddressList`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/email-addresses-and-address-books/new-addresslist?view=exchange-ps#optional-parameters

Specifically:

> If you don't use this parameter,the address list is created under the root (\).
>
> ...
>
> Default value:    None

```
$container = $null
New-AddressList -Container $container

# or...

$container = "\"
New-AddressList -Container $container
```

Answer (score -1):

take a look at `Get-Help *splatting` to see a way to do this.

a bit more detail ... a "splat" is a hashtable of `parameter = value` pairs. once you have the basic always-there items in the splat, you can add others just as you would to any hashtable by `$Param_Splat.Add(ParameterName, 'Value')`. then when you call your cmdlet, you use `Verb-Noun @Param_Splat`. note the `@` symbol instead of the usual `$`. [*grin*]

take care,
lee