# Adding optional Parameters to a command with if

Tags: powershell

im trying to add parameters to a command dependending on if a variable is set like:

```
Enter-PSSession $hostname if($cred) {-Credential $cred} if($verbose) {-Verbose}
```

Is there a way to do it like I tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to omit powershell parameter from cmdlet if value not provided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586848/how-to-omit-powershell-parameter-from-cmdlet-if-value-not-provided)

Comment: Thank you that‘s exactly what i‘m looking for!